# After introducing an acronym, how faithfully must I stick to its use?

Tags: writing-style, writing, acronyms

My average scientific paper contains about a dozen of acronyms. Some of them are really helpful: for example, it much more pleasant to write fMRI instead of functional magnetic resonance imaging.

However, I really dislike writing long sentences containing several acronyms. It makes the content difficult to understand for those who are not that familiar with my (sub-)field.

It would be sometimes better to write the acronym in full. However, how "acceptable" is this after introducing an acronym?

In long papers, I would also sometimes like to write out the acronym in full in a new section (e.g., when moving from methods to results and discussion). Some co-authors do not like that.

What is the correct thing to do?

(The use of acronyms – at all – is typically partly dictated by the journal I submit to. Most of them ask to use an acronym instead of writing the name in full if it appears at least thrice in a manuscript.)

Comment: As it happens, I also do fMRI research. Follow the guidelines of the journal, there is no need to reintroduce it at the beginning of a section. I have started a paper in the middle, found an acronym and went back to find it. It's not that big of a deal

Comment: If you use LaTeX, and possibly even if you don't, a browse of acronym-related questions at tex.stackexchange.com might be of interest. Although the questions there are about *how* to achieve a particular effect, the discussion and background may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For a scientific paper, most publications dictate that you write the term in full the first time you use it, followed by the the abbreviated form in parenthesis.

> - ...that can be easily diagnosed by Magnetic Ressonance Imaging (MRI)

All other times you are expected to use the acronym without parenthesis. If it's a long paper, and there are chapters, you are expected to write it in full the first time it is mentioned in each chapter.  As for using several acronyms, say 4 or 5 in a short sentence, I would use some creativity to avoid it.  If it can't be avoided at all, there is no problem provided the readers know what you are talking about.

Comment: +1 for rewording, this is often the best approach. I've given my take as well as we've seen different style guides.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the journal style guides I've seen is that once the acronym had been introduced you *may* use the short form after that. There are often situations where you might use the full version after this:

- Sometimes you are required to use the long form in figure captions (at least at the first occurrence per figure) .
- Sometimes the term is really needed at the beginning of a sentence and it's often regarded as bad form to start a sentence with an acronym.

Remember that clarity must come first. This can easily mean that the long form is required after the acronym has been introduced.